# How can I add Slidingpanelyout programatically?

Tags: android, layout

I want to add Slidingpanelayout to my project by code like this:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams fp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(activity);
```

I found this widget [Slidingpanelayout.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.java) but I can't figure out how to import it to my project. All tutorials I found just import it through XML layout file.

Answer (score 1):

use this https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/blob/master/README.md

```
setEnabled(false)
```

-you can now completely disables the sliding panel (touch and programmatic sliding)

Comment: Sorry but I need to slide from left to right, not up.